# How to properly store this value-pair table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table that looks like the below. There are many entities (100,101, etc.) The Attribute Group definitions are the same, but could change over time. For instance, next month Group 1 could be 0-105.

I'm trying to figure out a way to structure this data so that an entity has a single row for each date, but am unsure how best to handle the changing group definitions since the table will add new data each month.

```
.--------.-----------.------------------.-------.
| ENTITY |   DATE    |    ATTRIBUTE     | VALUE |
:--------+-----------+------------------+-------:
|    100 | 3/31/2020 | GROUP 1: 0-100   |   2.5 |
:--------+-----------+------------------+-------:
|    100 | 3/31/2020 | GROUP 2: 100-200 |   8.9 |
:--------+-----------+------------------+-------:
|    100 | 3/31/2020 | GROUP 3: 201-300 |   1.2 |
:--------+-----------+------------------+-------:
|    100 | 3/31/2020 | GROUP 4: 301-400 |   9.4 |
:--------+-----------+------------------+-------:
|    100 | 3/31/2020 | GROUP 5: 401-500 |    22 |
:--------+-----------+------------------+-------:
|    100 | 3/31/2020 | GROUP 6: 501-600 |     9 |
:--------+-----------+------------------+-------:
|    100 | 3/31/2020 | GROUP 7: 601-700 |   1.1 |
'--------'-----------'------------------'-------'
```

EDIT:

I ultimately want data that resembles this.

```
  ENTITY     DATE      GROUP 1   GROUP 2   GROUP 3   GROUP 4  
 -------- ----------- --------- --------- --------- --------- 
     100   3/31/2020       2.5       8.9       1.2       9.4
```

Another table can store the group definitions since they could change over time.

```
     FROM           GROUP        
 ------------ ------------------ 
  12/31/2020   GROUP 1: 0-100    
  12/31/2020   GROUP 2: 100-200  
  12/31/2020   GROUP 3: 201-300  
  12/31/2020   GROUP 4: 301-400
```

I'm missing how best to link these two. I.e., if wanted to join the tables to see what Group 1 actually meant, how that could be accomplished.

EDIT 2:

My original example isn't as clear as it should be. This is more representative of the type of data I'm working with.

```
  ENTITY     DATE            ATTRIBUTE          VALUE  
 -------- ----------- ------------------------ ------- 
  APPLE    3/31/2020   Employee Age #1: 0-16    0%     
  APPLE    3/31/2020   Employee Age #2: 17-19   5%     
  APPLE    3/31/2020   Employee Age #3: 20-22   13%    
  GOOGLE   3/31/2020   Employee Age #1: 0-16    0%     
  GOOGLE   3/31/2020   Employee Age #2: 17-19   15%    
  GOOGLE   3/31/2020   Employee Age #3: 20-22   25%
```

Comment: Check normalization on wikipedia. You would get those groups and values to a new table. Depending on how you use that data, you could also use an xml or json (string) field.

Comment: I’m stuck on the fact that the groups and values are meaningless without the entity.

Comment: @DaleK will do that. any suggestions how to link that group definition table back to the entity and value?

Comment: @DaleK  edited my post - having some trouble figuring out how these tables would be connected.

Comment: @DaleK, i updated my example to data example to something closer to what im actually working with. could you check it out and see if your approach would change?

Answer (score 0):

I think I better understand now what you are trying to achieve. The best data structure for this job is actually dependent on more details (BTW in your groups second row is 100-200, probably should be 101, otherwise 100 matches to 2 groups). With normal normalization rules it would be something like this:

```
CREATE table myEntities (
    entityId int identity not null primary key,
    entity int --, other entity details 
);

Create table myGroups (groupId int not null primary key,
  fromDate date null, untilDate date null,
  rangeLow int not null, rangeHigh int not null,
);

Create table myEntityDetails (detailId int identity not null primary key,
  entityId int not null references MyEntities(entityId),
  groupId int not null references myGroups(groupId),
  [date] date,
  [value] decimal (10,2)
);
```

Sampled with your data:

```
insert into myEntities (entity) values (100);

insert into myGroups 
(groupId, rangeLow, rangeHigh, [fromDate], [untilDate]) 
values
(1, 0, 100, '20191231', null),
(2, 100, 200, '20191231', null),
(3, 201, 300, '20191231', null),
(4, 301, 400, '20191231', null),
(5, 401, 500, '20191231', null),
(6, 501, 600, '20191231', null),
(7, 601, 700, '20191231', null);

INSERT INTO myEntityDetails
(entityId, groupId, [date], [value])
VALUES
(1, 1, '20200331', 2.5),
(1, 2, '20200331', 8.9),
(1, 3, '20200331', 1.2),
(1, 4, '20200331', 9.4),
(1, 5, '20200331', 22),
(1, 6, '20200331', 9),
(1, 7, '20200331', 1.1);
```

You can either check the plain view:

```
Select e.entityId, e.entity, 
   d.[Date], g.RangeLow, g.rangeHigh, d.[Value]
from myEntities e
inner join myEntityDetails d on e.entityId = d.entityId
INNER JOIN myGroups g ON g.groupId = d.groupId 
WHERE d.[date] >= ISNULL(g.fromDate, '20000101') AND 
d.[date] < ISNULL(g.untilDate, '99990101');
```

Or pivot (cross tab) this data based on the above plain above:

```
SELECT pvt.entityId,
       pvt.entity,
       pvt.date,
       pvt.[1],
       pvt.[2],
       pvt.[3],
       pvt.[4],
       pvt.[5],
       pvt.[6],
       pvt.[7]
FROM (
Select e.entityId, e.entity, 
   d.[Date], g.groupId, d.[Value]
from myEntities e
inner join myEntityDetails d on e.entityId = d.entityId
INNER JOIN myGroups g ON g.groupId = d.groupId 
WHERE d.[date] >= ISNULL(g.fromDate, '20000101') AND 
d.[date] < ISNULL(g.untilDate, '99990101')
) plainView
PIVOT (SUM([Value]) FOR groupId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) pvt;
```

You can find [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80c92f37de3851f58d8d6cd51dea32af) here.

If the structure of groups is constant, and the data would be flooding like a sensor data per second, then an alternative "denormalized" data would be suggested (almost identical to the end result). IOW, your details would be the decision maker on the structure.

EDIT: Maybe I would change it just a little bit depending on your edit:

[DBFiddle demo is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d81fe05d9c0c7bca055766244e7b6d3)

Comment: Thank you, I think i'm getting there. I updated my example to something that closer represents the data I'm actually dealing with. Would you change your approach based on the new data?